# Debugging a DLL through a program

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, dll

So i have an open source project to which i made changes to and produced a dll.

Next i used that dll in a project of mine.

However there are some problems in the changes i made so i wanted to apply some breakpoints to my code in dll so i can check some variable values.

Is it possible to apply breakpoints in DLL and then when my program uses that dll for function calls, the breakpoints in the dll source that i put gets activated gets activated.

I have searched the internet and it is really confusing and since i am new i really have no idea on how to proceed.

I just wanted to breakpoint activated that i have inserted in the source.

Comment: If you're modifying the code for the DLL, why not include the code in your solution and use it as a project reference?  Then debugging into it would be like any other project in your solution.

Comment: Well the project is really large and has many dependencies on other open source projects in itself.

Comment: Ok, but you're already modifying and re-compiling it anyway.  So you have those dependencies resolved already.

Comment: Since the project is so large and complex i think i will include the whole solution of dll in my application solution. Is right and possible ?

Comment: +1 Good Job on being clear on what you were looking for and being able to communicate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add both projects together in a solution and make a [project reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the open source project from your project. Once this is complete you can set a break point where ever in the open source project and it will break just like your project. Just make sure everything is in [debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wx0123s5.aspx) mode.

Comment: I just arrived at the same solution myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You debug a process. Either start your program with the debugger, or attach it afterwards. Then set breakpoints on the code or functions within your DLL.

Some debuggers will let you add breakpoints on a module before it is loaded (say your DLL is loaded later in the process execution).

Comment: So the breakpoints i set in the source of dll are activated once the process using them starts with a debugger ?

Comment: Start by debugging the process. Then set a breakpoint on the code in your DLL. If the DLL has not been loaded, then depending on the debugger, you may have to wait to set the breakpoint until the DLL in memory.